# Setting up mock objects for Google test suite on legacy C code?

Tags: mocking, googletest, googlemock

I want to create mock objects for legacy C api's. What is the effective way for it? I have also read somewhere that creating stub class could help me in this but here also I am not sure what is the recommended approach for it. 
Is is okay to first create Stub class and then create mock class over it? Please share your opinion.

-Bhupesh

Answer (score 0):

Google Mock calls C-style functions ["free functions."](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions) They can be mocked by first creating an interface, which is just an abstract class in C++.

The example they give:

```cpp
class FileInterface {
 public:
  ...
  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) = 0;
};

class File : public FileInterface {
 public:
  ...
  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) {
    return OpenFile(path, mode);
  }
};
```

Instead of directly calling `Open(...)`, use an instance of `FileInterface`, which may be mocked for use in tests.

---

Mocks can be used like stubs; just don't set any expections on the object...use only the `ON_CALL` methods.

Comment: Yes exactly but how can I do that in C function which is more than 700 line long.. and It does not just do one thing... it does almost all...
I am bit afraid...

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean. If you can provide more details, please update your question. The length of the function does not impact its ability to be mocked.